# $_POST['email']; Not printing given value of 'email' in an input?

Tags: php, html

What I have done is given the index for the site an input for the user to enter their email, however, the PHP echo command isn't printing anything out. However, When I replace it all with just an '`echo`' command with `<p>` tags on each side of the to-be-echoed string, it'll echo all the rest of the PHP, including the '`?>`' at the end!

```
    <article>
        <form action="my.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email"><br />
            <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </article>
```

And the PHP is as follows:

```
     <ul>
        <li>
            <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Try to just do `var_dump($_POST);` on the page instead, to make sure that *something* is coming through in the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: *it'll echo all the rest of the PHP* — that means the PHP isn't running at all. See the duplicate question.